# How to get the textbox name of current sorting SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I enabled interactive sorting on some textbox inside a table, I need put the textbox name to one expression, so visitor know which sorting is using for this table.

How can I get it? Is there a formula or report parameter to use?

Comment: i did a little bit of poking around in ssrs, and didn't find anything that looked like you could grab info from the table about its sorting.

Comment: Do you think we can store textbox name to a variable in sorting expression?

Comment: @atu0830, why don't you use a parameter for let your users choose the column to sort? This approach is more flexible than the built-in interactive sorting feature and your user will know how the tablix is sorted easily.